# Master Page CSS and Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, master-pages

I'm not pretty sure what I've done wrong here every thing seems fine 
but once I added the absolute path for it it sopped working neither the pages within the same folder nor the pages in other folders

```
<link id="Link1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/Master.css" runat="server"/>
        <link id="Link2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/sooperfish.css" media="screen" runat="server"/>
        <link id="Link3" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/sooperfish-theme-large.css" media="screen" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried

```
...href="<%=ResolveUrl("~")%>styles/Master.css"...
```

This works for me normally.

This is because the application home path is with a subdirectory in it and it cannot resolve it through the browser.

Hope it helps.